# How to use link instead of string in this custom javascript function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, localization

I have a helper function to replace params in a string with the params provided -

```
type FormatStringParameter = string | number;

/**
 * Temporary function to replace params in a string with the params provided
 *
 * @param input The string that has params i.e. {0}, {1}...
 * @param params An array of strings representing the params
 */
export function formatString(input: string, ...params: FormatStringParameter[]): string {
  if (params && params.length) {
    for (let i = 0; i < params.length; ++i) {
      input = input && input.replace(`{${i}}`, params[i] as string);
    }
  }

  return input;
}
```

The string variables are:

```
const str = "Hello World! {0}"
const linkText = "Click Here!"
```

How can I use the `formatString` function to display the text = `Hello World! Click Here!` with 'Click Here!' being a link (not plain text)

I tried `const outputText = formatString(str, linkText);` but since the `formatString` function only takes string as input, I am getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

That is not so easy.

The hardest part would be to split the string `input` into a list of strings and links, and probably to determine if an individual `param` should be a link or a normal text.

`formatString` needs to export a DOM node, or an array of DOM nodes, instead of a string.

But also the code that calls `formatString` needs to be able to handle DOM nodes, so only fixing `formatString` is not enough.

A quick (incomplete) example of creating DOM links:

```
function formatString( input, ...params ){
    const result = [];
    for( let i = 0; i < params.length; ++i ){
        if( shouldBeLink ){
            const element = document.createElement('a');
            element.appendChild( document.createTextNode( params[i] ))
            result.push( element );
        } else if( ... ){
        ...
    }

    return result;
}
```

For the sake of completeness: React also lets you write HTML code directly into an element (including links), but that is dangerous and you should not do it. That's why it's called ['dangerouslySetInnerHTML'](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml).

Answer (score 0):

Two observations **:**

- How you will identify that the element inside `params` array is a link or plain text ?
- On click where user will get redirect ? Where is the `link` URL given ?

If you have all the elements as a link in the `params` array, Then you can simply replace them with HTML `<a>` tag inside replace function itself.

```js
function formatString(input: string, ...params: string[]) {
  console.log(params);
  if (params && params.length) {
    for (let i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
      input = input && input.replace(`{${i}}`, `<a href="#">${params[i]}</a>`);
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = input;
}

const str = "Hello World! {0}"
const linkText = "Click Here!"

formatString(str, linkText);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```